# How to handle the click event on all the polylines when the cursor is on overlapped polylines?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onclick, google-polyline

I have many polylines on map and, if the user click some, I want to "select" the intended polyline, but sometimes polylines can get overlapped. So, if the user wants to select one and click on 2, I want to know what the polylines were clicked by the user and display it. How can I do that?

I tried to write some code that loops the polylines and checks if the clicked location is on some drawing, but does not work because click on drawings does not mean click on the polyline geolocation.

Here's my code: ([Run in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigox10/Lro8gj9x/9/))

```
// this example creates 2 polylines (one red, one blue) and add event listener
// to "click", and the handler loops over "polylines" (an array with the 2 
// polylines created)

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {
            lat: -25,
            lng: -50
        },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    var isOnPolyline = function (point, polyline) {
        if (point instanceof google.maps.Marker) {
            point = point.getPosition();
        }
        return google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(point, polyline, 0.0001) ||
            google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, polyline);
    };

    var red = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{
            lat: -25.006,
            lng: -52
        },
        {
            lat: -25.006,
            lng: -51
        }
        ],
        map: map,
        name: "red",
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 10
    });

    red.addListener("click", function (e) {
        polylines.map(function (p) {
            if (isOnPolyline(e.latLng, p)) {
                console.log("hey, you clicked the " + p.name + " one");
            }
        });
    });

    var blue = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [{
            lat: -25,
            lng: -53
        },
        {
            lat: -25,
            lng: -50
        }
        ],
        name: "blue",
        map: map,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#0000FF',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 6
    });
    blue.addListener("click", function (e) {
        polylines.map(function (p) {
            if (isOnPolyline(e.latLng, p)) {
                console.log("hey, you clicked the " + p.name + " one");
            }
        });
    });

    var polylines = [red, blue];
}
```

so I tried to click as shown in the figure (cursor is the yellow circle):

[image]

I expected the console logs:

"hey, you clicked the red one

hey, you clicked the blue one"

But nothing was logged.

Comment: There is no yellow marker in the posted code (or fiddle), where did that come from?

Comment: but there really is no such marker, the yellow circle represents the position of cursor when the click is fired. I'm just saying "hey, I'm clicking here over 2 polylines, let me know it"